# htaccess file to remove .php but still can access folder

Tags: .htaccess

I'm a little bit confuse about my htaccess, I want to remove all (dot)php extension on my URLs. Here's my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [NC,L]
```

I put the htaccess file on folder `app`. when I tried to access it from index.php to app/index.php it returns an error, it said no POST data. What should I add to the htaccess file so it can be access my folder?

Comment: What URL are you typing in browser?

Comment: first one is `localhost/myproject/index.php` target when a form submitted is `localhost/myproject/app/index.php`

Comment: Use `localhost/myproject/app/` for form submit and test after clearing browser cache

Comment: Yes, internally, you should be submitting the request to the canonical URL as anubhava suggests. `.htaccess` alone should not be used to change your URLs (ie. remove the `.php` extension) - you still need to actually change the URL in your HTML source. (The redirect in `.htaccess` is _only_ for SEO. 301s end up converting the request to a GET, so any POST data is lost.)

Comment: @anubhava what if my form submit target is `myproject/app/test.php`  ?

Comment: btw. it's work after I test the link to `app/` but still, what if I want to another link like `test.php` or `mysubmit.php` or else

Comment: Don't do form submit to `myproject/app/test.php`, just use `myproject/app/test`

Comment: ooh.. it works.. so i have to remove that PHP manually then.. I got it now. Thank you so much! @anubhava